# Win CLI: Get Tomcat drive

Tags: dos

I am running the following command to get Tomcat location from the Registry.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=REG_SZ" %t in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\5.5" /v InstallPath | find "REG_SZ"') do set drive=%t
```

The output is `set drive=  C:\Tomcat 5.5`

It looks like the the chars between = and C:\ are not spaces, since my command to substitute spaces for nothing: `set drive=%drive:  =%` does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a tab. Replacing works only in a batch file.

```
set drive=%drive:   =%
```